# Window which blocks all other window in my app (options window)

Tags: wpf, window

I want to create a window from options and block other windows in my application.

Such a window is in the Visual Studio, for example - Tools -> Options.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your window is called `OptionsWindow`. You would just need to use the `ShowDialog()` method. Example:

```
var window = new OptionsWindow();
window.ShowDialog();
```

This will make the options window a modal dialog. All other windows will be disabled until the options window is closed.